# Good jQuery Mobile walkthrough or tutorial for a jquery developer?

Tags: jquery, mobile-phones, javascript-framework, jquery-mobile

### jQuery Mobile 1.0 final is out

**Important: Many of the tutorials are old and should not be followed. The current version of jQuery Mobile is 1.0! Please be careful while looking through the links**

*I have updated my answer to point out the right resources for final release*

---

I was wondering if there is a tutorial for people experienced with jQuery - to know some conventions for the new **[jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)** as it is going to be released soon. I especially like those that show how to make an example app, but please post what you consider best. *Only thing required is that it shows some use of JS and new events that jQueryMobile introduces.* So it's not a question about basic tutorials.

---

**OLD Basic tutorials:**

I've obviously googled for it and got these: http://blogfreakz.com/mobile-development/jquery-mobile-tutorials/ *[<- this links to a page linking to 5 tutorials]* which are showing the idea, but aren't really interesting for a jQuery developer.

This here has some actual jQuery code in it, but not much: http://thoughtsunlimited.net/intro-to-jquery-mobile/

---

So this question is mostly to people that have already tried out some tutorials and know what they'd recommend. I think this question might be useful to people in the future.

Bounty will be awarded to an answer that links to tutorials covering the largest number of methods available from jQueryMobile.

Comment: this one is nice for a start, but doesn't cover any javascript in fact... http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/

Comment: I will be creating a site to share jquerymobile resources I prepare for myself if bounty doesn't get me satisfying resources. If you're interested in getting answers not answering - be sure to revisit here after the bounty ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first-hand list of tutorials can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/resources/
I don't expect a better list to show up.

---

**jQuery Mobile dictionary** is a project I started to create a resource for people getting to know / using JQM to **quickly look up attribute or method names without browsing the docs**. It's updated for the 1.0 release!

http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/

---

Old links:

A tutorial that uses jqm beta 2, but it covers the whole site creation with PHP and stuff: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/08/jquery-mobile-product-website/

A bunch of tutorials I didn't check for versions:
http://webdesign14.com/8-useful-jquery-mobile-tutorials/

old [creating a mobile blog app](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1856)

Answer (score 18):

[edit] Some of the information below is outdated as *JQM 1.0 final* was released

Here are a few I have come across that I have found useful:

For those who are using Rails and the Devise authentication gem:
http://everydayrails.com/2010/11/09/jquery-mobile-rails-devise.html

Pretty thorough tutorial
http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-mobile-what-can-it-do-for-you

Has example zip
http://devgrow.com/mobile-web-dev-using-jquery-mobile

Short tutorial on ajax
http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1948

Comment: "what can it do" was on the list I posted. That ajax tutorial is a bit of what I expected - some code at last. Thanks for new links. The bounty remains open though - I hope to see some new jqmobile methods in action ;)

Comment: Glad I could contribute to the knowledge base :-)

Comment: If you're interested in contributing more - see my answer.

Comment: Nobody else wanted the bounty, so here you are.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing tutorials for Mobile (Android). My company created the tool [AppLaud](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/) (eclipse plugin for PhoneGap / Android). Detailed instructions and source coded provided. Support, too!

AppLaud includes the latest versions of PhoneGap (0.9.5 today) and jQuery Mobile (alpha 4.1 today).

[Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt0)

[All Tutorials](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials)

Latest: [jQuery Google Maps plugin / Map App on Android](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1)

Comment: Thanks. That's some good reference!

Answer (score 0):

Another tutorial, just for the list, don't think it is bounty worthy. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-jquerymobilejsontut/index.html

Comment: IBM got down to jquery mobile? cool :)

Comment: This tutorial is about jquery mobile alpha1, so it's a bit outdated