# Tutorials for Mobile Site using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have planned to create the mobile site using ASP.NET MVC. So, there is any good tutorial for start up ?

Comment: This might not be a duplicate, but I bet you could benefit from those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344259/good-jquery-mobile-walkthrough-or-tutorial-for-a-jquery-developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a new ViewEngine to do this for you: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Scott Hanselman's post on adding mobile capability](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx) or try this article [from the asp.Net site](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to try a tutorial that leverage's MVC3 and Razor:

[Using 51Degrees.Mobi Foundation for accurate mobile browser detection on ASP.NET MVC 3](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/)