# How to download jQM Galleries

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm looking for jQuery Mobile templates, and I find them at http://www.jqmgallery.com/, but I don't know how to download them.

Plz help me! Thanks very much!

Comment: There is no way to download it :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of just taking a look only at the first result of your [Google search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+mobile+examples),
 try another one, for example [this one](http://www.jquery4u.com/tag/jquery-mobile-examples/) or [this one](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/05/10-handy-jquery-mobile-tips-and-snippets-to-get-you-started/) ...
 hope that helps...

Another nice site for jQuery Mobile resources is [this one](http://jquerymobile.com/resources/), just visit the page you like and examine it with Firebug or another developer tool in your browser...

[More info see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344259/good-jquery-mobile-walkthrough-or-tutorial-for-a-jquery-developer)